# How to connect to a bluetooth a2dp device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I am trying to pair an android device running android 4.1 with a a2dp capable audio receiver. I can do that without problems from the bluetooth settings screen but i am struggeling to do it in code.

Basically i am able to discover the device but i can not connect to it via the socket. Maybe i am using the wrong UUID or maybe i should use the predefined android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp classes. Here is what i am doing:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
socket.connect();
```

But i get an exception stating that it can not connect.

```
java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:403)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:213)
```

I have also tried to connect using the UUIDs the device provides via `device.getUuids()` but those did not help either to connect to the a2dp device.

Any help on how to connect to an a2dp device would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you able to search and pair to this device

Comment: I can find the device when searching for devices. I was under the impression that creating a socket connection with a device automatically pairs them. Finding and pairing in the settings is no problem.

Comment: Hi Mortiz, could I ask if you ever got anywhere with this? I'm trying to connect a 4.2+ Android device to an A2DP Bluetooth speaker at the moment, and am struggling to work out how to approach it too. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hi @Ted. Unfortunately my research did not come to a successful conclusion.

Comment: How do you create the socket for bluetooth?

Answer (score 2):

A2DP is not done over RFCOMM, so you can't use the `createRfcommSocket` APIs.  The data is transported directly over L2CAP streams with specified protocol mux IDs (one for control, another for streaming data).

Comment: could you go into a bit more detail on how to set up the connection?

Comment: It's not simple.  You need to open an L2CAP socket, which is not possible using the android java APIs.  You have to get into actual BlueZ programming in C.  Once you open an L2CAP socket, you have to implement AVDTP protocol.  You can find open source implementation in BlueZ source.  But it's going to be hard unless you have access to Bluetooth specs.

Comment: hm. not the answer i was hoping for. But thanks for jumping in. :)